# how to play custom voice in aws lex bot

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lex, amazon-connect

We are calling Lex bot from Amazon connect by using GetUserInput. Currently we are playing built-in voice (Jonna) from Lex. Now we want to play custom voice from Lex bot. Is it possible to play custom voice from Lex and Connect?

Thanks,
Ganesh

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Lex does not handle any text-to-speech. So any voice configuration will be in another service you use with your Lex bot.

---

AWS Connect only has a select number of options, in the "Set Voice" block:
[image: AWS Connect Voices List]

Custom voice is not an option in Connect.

---

Another service for text-to-speech that can easily connect with Lex is [Amazon Polly](https://console.aws.amazon.com/polly/home?region=us-east-1). Since Polly **focuses** on text-to-speech, it has a [long list of voices and languages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/voicelist.html).

However, it also does not support custom voices, but you may find the voice you want there.

---

There is good reason for not allowing custom voices though. You might not realize just how much goes into recording/building and preparing a single voice to be used to read ANY text.

Answer (score -1):

It is Impossible to play custom voice from lex bot. Just choose their voice while creating bot.